# ffmpeg not finding vcodec h264

Tags: ffmpeg

i am a newbie to ffmpeg and am using it on Windows. 
I tried to convert an avi file using the H.264 vcodec (h264). Got this error: Unknown encoder 'h264'. 
The 'Unknown encoder' error also showed up for mp3 for -acodec usage.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 16):

A few things:

1. Run the command `ffmpeg -codecs` to list the codecs your ffmpeg build supports.
2. `h264` and `mp3` are compression standards, but do not really identify a specific encoder.  The H.264 encoder that ffmpeg uses is x264 and you will either have to use `x264` or `libx264` in your command line depending on what is listed in #1.  The mp3 encoder is lame and usually is identified by something like `libmp3lame`.
3. You must have a version of ffmpeg that is built with support for these libraries since they are not directly part of ffmpeg.  If these codecs are not listed in `ffmpeg -codecs` you need to create or find a build that supports them.

Comment: This Ubuntu PPA supports them - https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg

Comment: link now broken

Answer (score 5):

Install `x264` and add run `./configure` in ffmpeg's directory, using these flags:

```
--enable-gpl 
--enable-shared 
--enable-libx264
--extra-cflags="-I/path/to/include" 
--extra-ldflags="-L/path/to/lib"
```

where `-I/path/to/include` is likely `-I/usr/local/include` and `-L/path/to/lib` is likely `-L/usr/local/lib`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enabled the 'h264' encoder while configuring the FFmpeg. 'h264' encoders comes under GPL.

Answer (score 0):

Info on building ffmpeg with libx264:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20quickly%20compile%20FFmpeg%20with%20libx264%20(x264,%20H.264)

Comment: link now broken