# Problem with saving a python animation as mp4

Tags: python, animation

I'm having a problem saving the python animation in the code below.
I looked at this post:
[ffmpeg not finding vcodec h264](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582602/ffmpeg-not-finding-vcodec-h264)
but it didn't help me.
If someone can show me how to solve it in a step by step process I'll be grateful.
This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, writers

x_data = []
y_data = []

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 105)
ax.set_ylim(0, 12)
line, = ax.plot(0, 0)

def animation_frame(i):
    x_data.append(i * 10)
    y_data.append(i)

    line.set_xdata(x_data)
    line.set_ydata(y_data)
    return line, 

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animation_frame, frames=np.arange(0, 10, 0.1), interval=10)

# setting up wrtiers object
Writer = writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata={'artist': 'Me'}, bitrate=1800)

animation.save('Line Graph Animation.mp4', writer)
```

And this is the error I'm receiving:
subprocess.CalledProcessError(
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ffmpeg', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-s', '640x480', '-pix_fmt', 'rgba', '-r', '15', '-loglevel', 'error', '-i', 'pipe:', '-vcodec', 'h264', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-b', '1800k', '-metadata', 'artist=Me', '-y', 'Line Graph Animation.mp4']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: Did you install ffmpeg?

Comment: yes i did install it

Comment: The code works on my machine (windows 10, ffmpeg version 4.3.1, matplotlib 3.6.1). Maybe a version issue?